# Replication applying daily snapshots to subscriber

Tags: sql-server, replication, snapshot

I've setup a very basic snapshot based publication and have a single subscriber and that all works ok for the initial snapshot. I've scheduled the snapshot agent to generate nightly snapshots and that is all good as well. However, the subscriber didn't take the snapshot generated on the 2nd evening. So I set the subscriber to reinitialise and the new snapshot was applied so all good.

My question therefore is: what did I miss? Why did the subscriber not take the new snapshot and I had to force a re-init. I have found that I can do the following programatically and if this is the way, then I can schedule this:

```
exec sp_reinitsubscription @publication = 'My-Snapshot-Publication', @subscriber = 'all'
```

But it feels like I missed something, a setting maybe to force invalidation/reinitialize on every snapshot generation? does such setting exist? are there other ways? or do I have to force a re-init like the above for each publication to apply the nightly snapshot?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing exactly how you set everything up. Subscriptions are synchronized by the Distribution Agent (for snapshot and transactional replication). The agent can run continuously, run on demand, or run on a schedule. Did you specify a synchronization schedule for the Distribution Agent?

Comment: hi @BrandonWilliams. the distribution agent is running continuously. It picks up the snapshot the first time around, but subsequent snapshots, it just states in the logs "no replicated transactions are available" even though a newer snapshot exists in the fileshare. If i reinit the subscription (like the above), the distribution agent immediately applies the new snapshot..

Comment: Something doesn't feel right... when i look in MSdistribution_agents, i see two virtual subscribers in addition to the single actual subscriber.. i'm going to rebuild the publication later and see if that helps.

Comment: Ok i think i have found the issue. I have transactional replication already running in the same publishing database as the one i'm trying to add a nightly snapshot replication to. The distribution agent seems to be getting confused when calling sp_MSget_repl_commands as it was using a much later seq_no thus thinking there isn't a newer snapshot to apply. I think my only option is reinit the subscriber each evening thus forcing it to use the prepared snapshot each day.. If anyone can shed any further light on this, that'll be great.